# Show that $(X_{n},Y) \to^{\mathcal{D}} (X,Y)$ AND if $X=h(Y)$ where $h$ is a Borel function that $X_{n}\to^{P} X$

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables, weak-convergence

> Let $X_{n}$, $X$, and $Y$ be real-valued r.v.'s all defined on the same space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A},\mathbb P)$. Assume that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\mathbb E\{f(X_{n})g(Y)\}=\mathbb E\{f(X)g(Y)\}$ whenever $f$ and $g$ are bounded, and $f$ is continuous, and $g$ is Borel. Show that the sequence $(X_{n}, Y)$ converges in law to $(X,Y)$. If furthermore $X=h(Y)$ for some Borel function $h$, show that $X_{n}\to^{\mathbb P} X$.

I have made several attempts at proving the first part, and have failed (see comments below). The second part I am not sure how to prove either.

Comment: Your first step is not complete.  To show that $(X_n, Y) \to (X,Y)$ in distribution, you have to show that $E[k(X_n, Y)] \to E[k(X,Y)]$ for *every* bounded continuous function $k(x,y)$ -- not just those $k$ which can be written in the form $k(x,y) = f(x) g(y)$.

Comment: Okay, here's my second go at the first part: there is a theorem that states that $X_{n}\to^{\mathcal{D}} X$ iff $\lim_{n \to \infty}E\{g(X_{n})\}=E\{g(X)\}$ for all bounded uniformly continuous functions $g$. Now, if a function is uniformly continuous, it is certainly continuous. Let $k(X_{n})$ be a uniformly continuous bounded function. Also, let $W_{n}=(X_{n},Y)$, $W=(X,Y)$. Then, by assumption, $\lim_{n \to \infty}E\{k(W_{n})g(Y)\}=E\{k(W)g(Y)\}$. Since this holds for all bounded Borel $g$, choose $g(Y)=1$. Then, we have $\lim_{n \to \infty}E\{k(W_{n})\}=E\{k(W)\}$

Comment: (CONTINUED): which implies that $\lim_{n \to \infty} E\{k(Xn,Y)\}=E\{k(X,Y)\}$. And since $k$ is an arbitrary bounded, uniformly continuous function, by the theorem, we have that $(X_{n},Y)\to^{\mathcal{D}}(X,Y)$. Better?

Comment: Sorry, not better.  None of your assumptions justifies the claim that $\lim_{n \to \infty}E\{k(W_{n})g(Y)\}=E\{k(W)g(Y)\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof of the convergence in distribution of $(X_n,Y)$ to $(X,Y)$ is done [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/854303/show-lim-limits-n-to-infty-mathbf-efx-ngy-mathbf-efxgy/895057#895057) (the use of characteristic functions could make it shorter).

Assume that $X=h(Y)$ for some Borel function $h$. Using the assumption with $g:=f\circ h$, a bounded Borel-measurable function, we obtain that for each continuous and bounded function $f$, 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\mathbb E[f(X_n)f(X)]=\mathbb E[f(X)^2].$$
Noticing that $f^2$ is a continuous bounded function, we obtain that 
$$\tag{*}\lim_{n\to \infty}\mathbb E[(f(X_n)-f(X))^2]=0.$$

Let $\varepsilon\gt 0$. For a fixed $R$, we have 
$$\mathbb P\{|X_n-X|\gt\varepsilon\}\leqslant \mu\{|X_n|\gt R\}+\mu\{|X|\gt R\}+\mathbb P\{|X_n-X|\gt\varepsilon, |X_n|\leqslant R,|X|\leqslant R\}.$$
Consider $f$ a continuous bounded function such that $f(x)=x$ on $[-R,R]$. Then 
$$\mathbb P\{|X_n-X|\gt\varepsilon, |X_n|\leqslant R,|X|\leqslant R\}\leqslant \varepsilon^{-2}\mathbb E[(f(X_n)-f(X))^2\chi(|X_n|\leqslant R,|X|\leqslant R\})]\leqslant \varepsilon^{-2}\mathbb E[(f(X_n)-f(X))^2],$$
hence for each $R$
$$\limsup_{n\to +\infty}\mathbb P\{|X_n-X|\gt\varepsilon\}\leqslant \sup_n\mu\{|X_n|\gt R\}+\mu\{|X|\gt R\}.$$

Using the fact that $X_n\to X$ in distribution, we obtain that the RHS goes to $0$ as $R$ goes to infinity.

Comment: After the line "Consider $f$ a continuous ... equal to $1$" you use the inequality $|x_n -x|^2 \leq (f(x_n)-f(x))^2$. Is this justified? Choosing $f(x) = x$ for $|x|\leq R$ would leave the problem that the bound of how quick (*) holds, might depend on $R$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant $f(x)=x$ for $|x|\lt R$.