# Show $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\mathbf E(f(X_n)g(Y))=\mathbf E(f(X)g(Y))$

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence

> Let $X_n,X,Y$ be real valued random variables, defined on the same space. Assume that $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\mathbf E(f(X_n)g(Y))=\mathbf E(f(X)g(Y))$$ for all $f$, continuous and bounded and for all $g$ bounded and Borel. Prove that $(X_n,Y)$ converges in law to $(X,Y)$

Is $\displaystyle\mathbf E(f(X_n)g(Y))=\int\int f(x)g(y)P^{X_n}(dx)P^{Y}(dy)$ ?

and $P^{X_n}(dx)$ and $P^{Y}(dy)$ are equal, since they're defined on the same probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal A,P)$ ?

Comment: No, there is no reason why $P^{X_n}$ and $P^Y$ should be equal. Are you familiar with Lévy's continuity theorem?

Comment: @Siméon I think that is the next chapter.

Comment: Ok, so what are the sufficient conditions for convergence in law that you know of?

Comment: @Siméon $E(\psi(x_n,y))\to E(\psi(x,y))$, for $\psi$ bounded and continuous, and here we have only the product.

Comment: Then I would advise you to use the Stone-Weierstrass theorem.

Answer (score 1):

We have to prove that for each continuous and bounded function $\psi\colon\mathbf R^2\to\mathbf R$, we have 
$$\tag{*}\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb E[\psi(X_n,Y)]=\mathbb E[\psi(X,Y)].$$

We first prove that we can reduce to continuous functions with compact support. Then, for such functions, we can approximate by finite sums of functions involved in the assumption of the text, as suggested by Siméon.

Assume that we proved $(*)$ for $\psi$ continuous with compact support. Then consider for a fixed $R$ a continuous function $\eta_R$ which takes the value $1$ on the ball of center $0$ and radius $R$, and vanishes outside the ball centered at the origin and radius $R+1$. Then $\eta_R\psi$ is continuous with compact support. Noticing that $\lim_{R\to \infty}\sup_n\mathbb E[(1-\phi_R)(X_n,Y)]=0$, we obtain that (*) holds for each continuous and bounded function.

Let $\psi$ be a continuous function with compact support. We can assume that it is contained in $[-R,R]^2$ for some $R$. By the Stone-Weierstrass theorem, we may approximate uniformly on $[-(R+1),R+1]$ the function $\psi$ by functions of the form $\psi_N:=\sum_{i=1}^Nf_i(x)g_i(y)$, $x,y\in\mathbf R$. Taking $h_R$ the one-dimensional equivalent of $\eta_R$ (except that we want it to vanish outside $[-(R+\delta),R+\delta]$ for a small $\delta$) and replacing $f_i$ by $f_ih_R$ and similarly for $g_i$, we obtain that the approximation takes place on $[-R,R]^2\cup(\mathbb R^2\setminus[-(R+\delta),R+\delta]^2)$. We thus obtain 
$$|\mathbb E[\psi(X_n,Y)-\psi(X,Y)]|\leqslant |\mathbb E[\psi_N(X_n,Y)-\psi_N(X,Y)|+|\mathbb E[\psi(X_n,Y)-\psi_N(X_n,Y)]|+|\mathbb E[\psi(X,Y)-\psi_N(X,Y)]|.$$
Since 
$|\mathbb E[\psi(X_n,Y)-\psi_N(X_n,Y)]|\leqslant 
\sup_{(x,y)\in [-R,R]^2\cup(\mathbb R^2\setminus[-(R+\delta),R+\delta]^2)}|\psi(x,y)-\psi_N(x,y)|+2\max\{\lVert \psi\rVert_\infty,\lVert \psi_N\rVert_\infty\}(\mathbb P\{X_n\in [R,R+\delta]\cup [-R-\delta,-R]\})$
we obtain by the assumption of the text that for each $N$,
$$\limsup_{n\to \infty}|\mathbb E[\psi(X_n,Y)-\psi(X,Y)]|\leqslant\sup_{(x,y)\in [-R,R]^2\cup(\mathbb R^2\setminus[-(R+\delta),R+\delta]^2)}|\psi(x,y)-\psi_N(x,y)|+2\max\{\lVert \psi\rVert_\infty,\lVert \psi_N\rVert_\infty\}\limsup_{n\to \infty}(\mathbb P\{X_n\in [R,R+\delta]\cup [-R-\delta,-R]\}+\mathbb P\{X\in [R,R+\delta]\cup [-R-\delta,-R]\}).$$
Using the fact that $X_n\to X$ in distribution (take $g=1$ in the assumption of the text) and assuming that $\pm R,\pm (R+\delta)$ are continuity points of the cdf of $X$, we obtain for such $R$ and $\delta$ that 
$$\limsup_{n\to \infty}|\mathbb E[\psi(X_n,Y)-\psi(X,Y)]|\leqslant\sup_{(x,y)\in [-R,R]^2\cup(\mathbb R^2\setminus[-(R+\delta),R+\delta]^2)}|\psi(x,y)-\psi_N(x,y)|\\+4\max\{\lVert \psi\rVert_\infty,\lVert \psi_N\rVert_\infty\}\mathbb P\{|X|\in [R,R+\delta]\}.$$
Since $\lVert \phi_N\rVert_\infty=\sup_{|x|,|y|\leqslant R}|\phi_N(x,y)|\leqslant \sup_{|x|,|y|\leqslant R}|\phi_N(x,y)-\phi(x,y)|+\lVert \psi\rVert_\infty$, the sequence $(\lVert\psi_N\rVert)_\infty$ is bounded and the conclusion follows.

Comment: I do not understand the second paragraph. Why is it clear that the limit as $R \to \infty$ of the supremum is zero? At some point, you need to use the fact that the hypotheses give you tightness, otherwise all you have from using compactly supported functions as your test functions is vague convergence.

Comment: Indeed, tightness is not completely trivial: we know that the sequence $(X_n)$ is tight, hence $P((X_n,Y)\notin [-R,R])=P(|X_n|>R\cup |Y|>R)\leqslant P(|X_n|>R)+P(|Y|>R)$.